# Converting a quadratically constrained optimization problem into a standard semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, qcqp, schur-complement

I have a constrained matrix optimization problem as follows
\begin{align} 
\max\limits_{X,Y} \;\; &tr\Big( X^T B X \Lambda \Big) + tr\Big( BY\Big) + tr\Big( X^T C \Lambda \Big) \\ 
\text{subject to} \;\; &-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q \Lambda X^T = X \Lambda X^T + Y \\
& Y \;\; \text{is symmetric positive-semi-definite} 
\end{align}
where $R$ is symmetric and $\Lambda$ is symmetric and positive-semi-definite. I can plug in the expression for $Y$ into the objective to get a linear objective function. Moreover, the equality constraint can be posed as the following PSD constraint: $-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q\Lambda X^T - X \Lambda X^T \succeq 0$. Using a Schur complement I can reformulate the constraint $-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q\Lambda X^T - X \Lambda X^T \succeq 0$ as the following PSD constraint: 
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
I & \Lambda^{1/2} X^T \\
X \Lambda^{1/2} & -\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q\Lambda X^T
\end{array}
\right] \succeq 0
\end{align}
Does this constraint convert the initial program into an SDP (in addition to imposition of the symmetry of $R^{-1}Q\Lambda X^T$ to ensure symmetry of $Y$)?

Comment: It looks like you already made a variable transformation. What is the original objective and problem definition (i.e. when you insert Y into the objective and simplify)? For scalars it simplifies to a linear expression, which would mean you probably have a linear objective with a convex quadratic inequality

Comment: @JohanLöfberg No this is the original form of the problem formulation itself, without any transformation of variables. But even when X and Y are scalars rather than matrices, this will give a quadratic objective with a quadratic constraint, unless I'm missing something

Comment: A quadratic equality constraint is unlikely to be convex.

Comment: As far as I can tell the objective simplifies to $tr X^TQ\Lambda /2$, hence you effectively have a problem with a linear constraint and the convex constraint $-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q \Lambda X^T - X \Lambda X^T \succeq 0$ (which you can write as a linear semidefinite constraint using a Schur complement)

Comment: ..."with a linear objective and the convex constraint"

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Actually I had made a mistake in the problem formulation. Do you have any ideas on converting the edited formulation into a standard form of any sort?

Comment: Don't you get a linear objective with that form too?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Yes, I worked it out: the objective is linear then too. But what about the symmetry constraint $R^{-1} Q \Lambda X^T = X \Lambda^T Q^T R^{-1^T}$, can that be posed as constraint that keep it as a SDP? Note that $R$ and $\Lambda$ are symmetric.

Comment: That's a linear equality which is trivial for all solvers.

Comment: Since you now edited it to involve a linear semidefinite constraint (since you use $\succeq$), you implicitly encode that the lower diagonal block is symmetric. A perhaps more clear form is to replace that term with a symmetric matrix $Z$ and add an equality $Z =-\frac{1}{2}R^{-1}Q\Lambda X^T$ to the model. That way, it is a very standard semidefinite program.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semidefinite-programming+qcqp

Comment: @JohanLöfberg as I read more about the standard form of SDPs, I must be able to express the PSD constraint (schur complement form) in the above program as an affine combination of symmetric matrices (which are problem data and given), but I failed to do so even in the simple case of $X$ being 2x2. How can I prove this is an SDP? Seems like it may not qualify as a standard SDP. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you *have* to... It is the standard (primal) form for solvers, but it is not necessarily the form you work with. If you *have to*, you introduce a new variable $Z$ which represent that whole expression in the LMI you obtained from the Schur, and then introduce all the linear inequalities required to make them match. Insanely boring and not something you do by hand. There is nothing to prove, the expression above is a symmetric matrix linearly parameterized, and you want it to be positive semidefinite. That's the definition of linear SDP. Beyond that is implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting the definition of $Y$in the objective and simplifying, the objective simplifies to $tr\Big( X^T C \Lambda - \frac{1}{2}BR^{-1}Q\Lambda ^T X^T \Big)$. The constraint $\frac{1}{2}BR^{-1}Q\Lambda ^T X^T - X\Lambda X^T \succeq 0$ is reformulated using a Schur complement.

Using a tool such as YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me) and an SDP solver, a model could then be

```
X = sdpvar(n,m,'full');
Z = sdpvar(n);
Model = [Z == .5*B*inv(R)*Q*Lambda'*X', [Z X;X' inv(Lambda)] >= 0]
Objective = trace(X'*C*Lambda - .5*B*inv(R)*Lambda*X');
optimize(Model,Objective);
```

If $\Lambda$ is singular, you factorize it as $\Lambda = SS^T$ and change the Schur complement accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the problem statement using your suggested reformulation. Does the Schur complement that I carried out above now turns the problem into an SDP?

Comment: It involves a semidefinite constraint, hence it is by definition amenable to semidefinite programming, Even better, it is linear, and thus solvable using a plethora of available SDP solvers.